# Segmentation Fault with Pointers and Strings

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am writing a pointer version of the C function strcat. It copies the string t to the end of s. This is my solution:

```
/* strcat: a pointer version of the strcat (copy string t to the end of s) */
void strcat (char *s, char *t)
{
    while (*s++ != '\0')    /* find the end of s */
        ;

    while (*s++ = *t++)
    ;
}
```

I ran it and it crashed - the Code Blocks debugger called it a segmentation fault, and that this part of the function was causing the crash:

```
while (*s++ = *t++)
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Write `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: How did you call your `strcat()`?

Comment: Did you allocate enough memory? If you show more of your code, it will be helpful.

Comment: By the way, there is a logical flaw in your implementation, after the first `while` loop, `s` will point to the character after the `\0` of first string, you need to add a `s--;` before you enter the second `while` loop.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to write a function with the same name as a standard function (or in fact with any name starting `str` followed by a lower case letter). You should call it something else such as `my_strcat`.  Another likely cause of your problem is if you are not actually passing in a buffer with enough writable space for `s`. Please post the whole program that crashes.

Comment: you never check for the end of t, so eventually s will equal invalid memory (because of *t++). You also never check the length of s. You could easily be writing outside the allocated size of s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fixed version and a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void strcat (char *s, char *t)
{
    while (*s++) 
        ;

    s--;

    while (*s++ = *t++)
        ;
}

int
main(void)
{
    char str1[100] = "abc";
    char *str2 = "def";
    strcat(str1, str2);
    printf("%s\n", str1);
    return 0;
}
```

---

If you call that `strcat()` in the following way,

```
char *str1 = "abc";
char *str2 = "def";
strcat(str1, str2);
```

then your program may crash, because compilers usually put string literals in read-only memory region, try to write to these places will cause segment fault.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I did try calling strcat using those two definitions. It makes sense now.